# unable to patch service name using kustomize

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kustomize

I am trying to rename my service using kustomize.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: couldn't find target core_v1_Service|~X|~P|SERVICE_NAME|~S for json patch
```

Here is my Base service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    version: IMAGE_TAG
  name: SERVICE_NAME
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-service
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http-service
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name:
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Here is my kustomization.yaml file where I have defined patchesJson6902:

```
patchesJson6902:
#- target:
#    group: apps
#    version: v1
#    kind: Deployment
#    name: DEPLOYMENT_NAME
#  path: patch_deployment.yaml
- target:
    group: core
    version: v1
    kind: Service
    name: SERVICE_NAME
  path: patch_service.yaml
```

I am able to replace my deployment name but not the service name. Kubectl Version: **1.16+**

my patch_deployment.yaml and patch_service.yaml files are very simple

```
- op: replace
  path: /metadata/name
  value: ${SERVICE_NAME}
```

Comment: Are you able to create service? Shouldn't you also specify namespace as your service yaml have `namespace: app` and your patch don't contain it?

Comment: Could you also provide your Deployment yaml?

Comment: What's inside patch_service.yaml and patch_deployment.yaml?

Comment: @PjoterS no I haven't specified anything as such in patch_deployment too but its working fine.

Comment: @VASャ I just edited my question top add patch_service.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few issues in your scenario.

First of all, in [selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) you are using downward api which will throw error:

```
error: error validating "svc.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.selector.app.kubernetes.io/name): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.selector: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors
```

Value here should be `string`. You could encounter similar situation if you would downward api in `PVC`. More information you can find [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57837).

Second issue is with `patchesJson6902`. If you will check example form [documentation](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/examples/kustomize.html) and find `service` example, there will be no `group: core` as below:

```
patchesJson6902:
- target:
    version: v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  path: add_init_container.yaml
- target:
    version: v1
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
  path: add_service_annotation.yaml
```

However, in your scenario, your `service` is using `namespace: my-namespace` so it should be also included in `patchesJson6902`.

There are two solution to make it working.

**Option 1**

Please keep in mind that your examples `SERVICE_NAME` and `IMAGE_TAG` will cause error:

```
The Service "SERVICE_NAME" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "SERVICE_NAME": a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', start with an alphabetic char
acter, and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is '[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

YAMLs below:

```
>cat svc.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    version: image-tag
  name: SERVICE_NAME
  namespace: my-namespace
 
>cat kustomization.yaml 
resources:
- svc.yaml
 
patchesJson6902:
- path: patch_service.yaml
  target:
    version: v1
    kind: Service
    name: SERVICE_NAME
    namespace: my-namespace
 
>cat patch_service.yaml 
- op: replace
  path: /metadata/name
  value: ${SERVICE_NAME}
 
>kustomize build 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    version: image-tag
  name: ${SERVICE_NAME}
  namespace: my-namespace
```

**Variable SERVICE_NAME wont be evaluated during kustomization. It has to be substituted afterwards using sed or manually.**

**Option 2**

It will require small script with [sed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) command.

```
>cat kustomization.yaml 
resources:
- svc.yaml
 
patchesJson6902:
- path: patch_service.yaml
  target:
    version: v1
    kind: Service
    name: SERVICE_NAME
    namespace: my-namespace
 
 
>cat kustomsed.sh 
#!/bin/bash
 
SERVICE_NAME=testsvc
 
kustomize build | sed "s/SERVICE_NAME/${SERVICE_NAME}/"
 
>./kustomsed.sh 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    version: image-tag
  name: testsvc
  namespace: my-namespace
```

Comment: This is not clear to me why `kustomize` requires `sed`. As a templating tool, shouldn't `kustomize` be able to fully manage yaml creation process?

Comment: @FabriceJammes `kustomize` is `surgical tool` without some boundaries and schema check, whilst sed is more general. In case there are cases couldn't achieve using kustomize (or difficult), we can use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is issue with kubectl kustomize version. It works with kustomize build.